# AS2 movie inside AS3 movie can't access flashvars... or any parent movie vars

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, actionscript-2, flashvars

Not my code, trying to fix it at the 11th hour.

Trying to access flashvars from a legacy AS2 movie loaded inside an AS3 movie

The AS3 movie uses com.gskinner.utils.SWFBridgeAS3 for AS2 compatibility.

The flashvars defined in the html file are not accessible in the AS2 movie. Not as "just variables" (old AS2 flashvars method) nor as the

```
stage.loaderinfo.parameters
```

which AS3 would provide.

Nothing seems to work, even accessing any variable defined in the parent AS3 movie.

So, in the AS3 movie:

```
var myvar = 5;
```

in the AS2 movie:

```
trace(myvar); => undefined
trace(parent.myvar); => undefined
```

How can I work around this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the information available on the SWFBridge site, you should do the following:

```
// in the AS2 SWF:
var myBridge:SWFBridgeAS2 = new SWFBridgeAS2("123456", clientObj);


// in the AS3 SWF:
var myBridge:SWFBridgeAS3 = new SWFBridgeAS3("123456", clientObj);
```

The ID 123456 can be any unique ID you would like to use.

Then, in the AS3 version:

```
var myvar = 5;
myBridge.send("updateVar", myvar);
```

In the AS2 version, have the following method:

```
function updateVar(var) {
    trace(var); // will output 5
}
```

Reference: http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2007/07/swfbridge_easie.html

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I needed!! I am new to actionscript and figuring this out was extra difficult.

Answer (score 0):

If you have working connection with as2 movie via SWFBridge, just pass those flashvars through it.

Comment: Again, not my code. Never used swfbridge. How do I find out if I have working connection? How do I pass the flashvars through it?Thank you!!